# Default values in Dynamic Switch in Manipulate

Tags: manipulate, dynamic

According to the following snippet:

```
Manipulate[{slide, cases},
 {{cases, "a"}, {"a", "b"}},
 Dynamic@Switch[cases,
   "a", Control[{{slide, 0.5, "Slider a"}, 0, 1}],
   "b", Control[{{slide, 0.1, "Slider b"}, 0, 1}]
   ]]
```

[image]

The value of slide is initialized to 0.1, and not 0.5 when, by default, the "a" case is selected, how to correct this behavior? In fact, even when "switching" between "a" and "b", it always take the default value of 0.1.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: Do you expect the value of `slide` to be reset whenever `cases` is changed? That is not how the initialization value works. Initialization happens when the `Manipulate` first starts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use [`TrackingFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TrackingFunction.html) and [`Dynamic`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dynamic.html).

```
Manipulate[
 {slide, cases},
 {{cases, "a"}, {"a", "b"},
  TrackingFunction -> {None, Automatic, Switch[#, "a", slide = .5, "b", slide = .1] &}},
 {{slide, 0.5, Dynamic@StringJoin["Slider ", cases]}, 0, 1}
 ]
```

The `TrackingFunction` on `cases` resets the value of `slide` when `cases` is updated.  The `Dynamic` on the `slide` label means that it will always show the current value of `cases`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Perfect, this is what I was looking for, I think nesting Manipulates is inelegant, and perhaps also difficult to read.

Answer (score 0):

One way to accomplish having the slider be dependent upon the position of the setter bar `cases` is to use nested `Manipulates`.

```
Manipulate[
 With[
  {
   controls = Switch[
     cases,
     "a",
     Control[{{slide, 0.5, "Slider a"}, 0, 1}],
     "b",
     Control[{{slide, 0.1, "Slider b"}, 0, 1}]
     ]
   },

   Manipulate[
   {slide, cases},
   controls]
  ], 

 {{cases, "a"}, {"a", "b"}}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]